# Crashes when pushing to viewcontroller - Objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My app getting crashed when I try to push to a view controller. Its happening only when we try to navigate to another page(both push and presentModal). And I also checked the `IBOutlets` and other connections in view controller where it should be pushed. But can't find a clue. Here is my code where I do the push:

```
PhoneBookView *phoneBook = [[PhoneBookView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhoneBook" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:phoneBook animated:YES];
```

Comment: show me the log message what it is saying...

Comment: Is PhoneBookView a view or a view controller?

Comment: @umersufyan It says nothing. Even it doesn't shows the -lldb in the console while crashing.

Comment: @Eiko its a view controller.

Comment: Run in debug mode in the simulator, maybe add an exception breakpoint. Without *any* message this seems impossible to solve.

Comment: go to product->Scheme->Edit Scheme-> change Debugger to GDB and in Diagnostic tab Enable Zombie Object

Comment: And - as iPatel probably wanted to point out - that presentModalViewController:animated: method has been deprecated in iOS 6.0.

Comment: @umersufyan I tried with the above method and run my code. It now saying as 'Program ended with exit code: 0' while crashing

Comment: please put the breakpoint on the view you are pushing yoi will be able to know that whether it is because og the navigation controller or other issue?

Comment: see below my answer..

Comment: I tried exception handing with try and catch blocks, and printed the exception and its logging as "Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/1028398D-0042-47C7-BBC8-1AF31A281807/TopBlip.app> (loaded)' with name 'PhoneBook'". but i have the xib named PhoneBook. Please help me out @umersufyan

Comment: Check whether your XIB's properly connect to view property. I think it is not connected and hence it is not able to find the XIB

Answer (score 1):

For you information `'presentModalViewController:animated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0`

try this:

```
PhoneBookView *phoneBook = [[PhoneBookView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhoneBookView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:phoneBook animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: My xib name is 'PhoneBook', so i think not need to use initWithNibName as"PhoneBookView".

Answer (score 0):

```
PhoneBookView *phoneBook = [[PhoneBookView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhoneBook" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:phoneBook animated:YES];
```

use the code present  view controller

```
PhoneBookView *phoneBook = [[PhoneBookView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhoneBook" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self presentModalViewController:phoneBook animated:YES];
```

and to push a view controller

```
PhoneBookView *phoneBook = [[PhoneBookView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhoneBook" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:phoneBook animated:YES];
```

Comment: I verified it and 'PhoneBook' is the correct xib name but its still crashing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 PhoneBookView *phoneBook = [[PhoneBookView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhoneBook" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:phoneBook];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

If you want to do push operation after Present the view ,then you need to add UINavigation controller as rootview controller for that Presenting View..

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

`[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:phoneBook animated:YES];` This method is deprecated

Instead you can use

```
[self presentViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#> completion:<#^(void)completion#>]

self presentViewController:phoneBook animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, no need to specify bundle,

```
PhoneBookView *phoneBook=[[PhoneBookView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhoneBook" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:phoneBook animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset iOS simulator, quit xcode and restart it , lets see if it helps you, this seems not your code fault, but xcode or simulator one.

Comment: I tried exception handing with try and catch blocks, and printed the exception and its logging as "Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/1028398D-0042-47C7-BBC8-1AF31A281807/TopBlip.app> (loaded)' with name 'PhoneBook'". but i have the xib named PhoneBook. Please help me out @umersufyan

Comment: send me your sample code. All i know your xib file is not attached to the File Owner to that class.

Answer (score -2):

Try with Following:

PhoneBookView *phoneBook = [[PhoneBookView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhoneBookView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

Comment: My xib name is 'PhoneBook', so i think not need to use initWithNibName as"PhoneBookView".